# Searching a specific columns of a table for not matching items

Tags: python, csv, comparison

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as test:
    reader = csv.reader(test, delimiter="\t")
    writer = csv.writer(table, delimiter="\t")
    for row in reader:
       for field in row:
            if field not in keywords:
                writer.writerow(row)
                break
```

It seems that this code writes out every row multiple times. I guess that it looks up every single field in each column. How can I specify a single column?

So this is the code I am using right now and it seems that it misses a few rows where the keyword is not present in any column.

```
table = open("table.txt", "w")
with open("test.txt", "r") as test:
    reader = csv.reader(test, delimiter="\t")
    writer = csv.writer(table, delimiter="\t")
    for row in reader:
        if all(field not in keywords for field in row):
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip` to get your columns then.You can use a generator expression within `all` function for checking that all the elements mett the condition  :

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as Spenn,open("test.txt", "r") as table:
    reader = zip(*csv.reader(Spenn, delimiter="\t"))
    writer = csv.writer(table, delimiter="\t")
    for row in reader:
        if all(field not in keywords for field in row):
            writer.writerow(row)
```

But if you just want to write the rows that meet the condition you can use the following code :

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as Spenn,open("test.txt", "r") as table:
    reader = csv.reader(Spenn, delimiter="\t")
    writer = csv.writer(table, delimiter="\t")
    for row in reader:
        if all(field not in keywords for field in row):
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: So this would now just extract the rows, which do not contain my keywords in any field, right?

Comment: @JadenBlaine I miss that you are looking for columns, you can use `zip` to search in columns, check out the edit!

Comment: No it was okay before the edit already, I got a typo in it and edited it in my original code now. But now I got a strange problem. Someone has written a Perl-Code for me to do the exact same task. The python code prints out 6360070 lines while the Perl code prints out 6364754 lines. Could it be that the python code might not find some special cases?

Comment: @JadenBlaine diff the files and see what's special about the missed lines maybe?

Comment: I think I figured it out, could it be that if I do not enter table.close() affects the output file? After running it again and then closing it, it seems to be identical to the output of the PerlScript

Comment: @JadenBlaine I edit the answer note that you need to open the `writer` file with `with` statement that close the file after process